# Excel 2010 - Need to condition P2 to highlight Yellow if P1 is greater than 33% and P2 is within the range value of 30%-33%

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

```
     O      P
```

1     Estimated        37%

2     Actual           32%

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is for Microsoft Excel and not C, select P2 and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(P1>0.33,P2>0.3,P2<0.33)
```

Format..., select Fill yellow, OK, OK.